# Rails: How do I force a new asset digest on ALL assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets, rails-sprockets

Running a rails 4.2 app with sprockets and using asset digests. When running `rake assets:precompile` it creates all my assets with digests. I need however to bump all asset digests to help me debug some caching stuff in production. I tried changing the assets version in:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '6.4'
```

However running `rake assets:precompile again after this is done, does not create new files with new digests`. Shouldn't it? Or am I missing out on something?

Comment: Are you using `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: In production yes, locally when debugging I didn't - does it make a difference?

Comment: I specify production when running assets:precompile locally since you most likely want it to use your production config.

Comment: How are you deploying your project? capistrano or something else? This setting has always worked for me.

Comment: Sprockets 3 broke this on Rails 4.  You can get around it via changing the prefix shown in my answer. https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the only way to force expiration of assets and get them recompiled was to add the following in my `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.version = '1.1' #This currently doesnt work as intended so use
config.assets.prefix = '/production'
```

Then `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Rails 4 and Sprockets 3 don't quite get along as per the thread here thus the versioning not working as intended: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/240

Comment: Interesting, you should add the link to the rails issue from the comment above into the answer

Comment: Thanks, Also it seems to have been restored in sprockets v4 (currently in BETA)